# MongoDB collection hyphenated name not working with "" from bash script

Tags: mongodb, bash, mongo-shell

Below is the bash script using for that:

There is issue with below command with ""
db.getCollection("name").count();
Inside mongo shell this command is working & returning the count:
db.getCollection("name").count();

```
mongo --host=$MONGO_HOST --port=$MONGO_PORT --username=$MONGO_USER --password=$MONGO_PASSWD --authenticationDatabase $DB_NAME --quiet --eval \
'var databases = db.getMongo().getDBNames();
  for(var i in databases){
    db = db.getMongo().getDB( databases[i] );
    if(db.getName() == "admin" || db.getName() == "config" || db.getName() == "local") {
        print("skipping db " + db.getName());
        continue;
    }
    print("----------------------")
    print("Using Database: " + databases[i]);
    var collections = db.getCollectionNames();
    for(var j = 0; j < collections.length; j++){
      var name = collections[j];
      if(name.substr(0, 6) != "system")
        var collectionCount = db.getCollection("name").count();
        var collectionSize = db.getCollection("name").dataSize();
        print(name + " - " + collectionCount +  " document(s)" + " & Collections Size: " + collectionSize + " Byte(s)");
    }
  }'
```

Returns all document count as 0 as below:
test_1 - 0 document(s) & Collections Size: undefined Byte(s)
test_2 - 0 document(s) & Collections Size: undefined Byte(s)
test_3 - 0 document(s) & Collections Size: undefined Byte(s)
test_4 - 0 document(s) & Collections Size: undefined Byte(s)
test_5 - 0 document(s) & Collections Size: undefined Byte(s)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `db.getCollection("name")` then you use literal `"name"` instead of the variable.

You missed the brackets. Your code

```
for (var j = 0; j < collections.length; j++) {
   var name = collections[j];
   if (name.substr(0, 6) != "system")
   var collectionCount = db.getCollection("name").count();
   var collectionSize = db.getCollection("name").dataSize();
}
```

is doing this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < collections.length; j++) {
   var name = collections[j];
   if (name.substr(0, 6) != "system") {
      var collectionCount = db.getCollection("name").count();
   }
   var collectionSize = db.getCollection("name").dataSize();
}
```

You can write the code a bit easier. I would do it as this:

```
var databases = db.getMongo().getDBNames();
for (var d of databases) {
   if (["admin", "config", "local"].includes(d)) {
      print("skipping db " + d);
      continue;
   }
   print("----------------------")
   print("Using Database: " + d);
   var collections = db.getSiblingDB(d).getCollectionNames();
   for (var c of collections) {
      if (!c.startsWith("system")) {
         var stats = db.getSiblingDB(d).getCollection(c).stats();
         print(`${c} - ${stats.count} document(s) & Collections Size: ${stats.size} Byte(s)`);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer it works. I have added another variable to convert bytes to MBs as below:

bytes=`echo "scale=2; (${stats.size}) / 1024^2" | bc`
print(`${c} - ${stats.count} document(s) & Collections Size: echo ${bytes} MB(s)`);

This doesn't print the required output value of bytes instead it prints variable content itself.